# Fatal error when using civicrm event form in 4.6.10

Tags: civievent

I received the following fall error when submitting the first event registration on a form I created. I have just updated to 4.6.10 on a new website.  Any help will be most welcome.

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /home/sites/rcsqsales.org.uk/public_html/fbabseil/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

I have The full backtrace and will post, if required.

Comment: I have also seen a similar error when clicking on Address Settings whilst going through the configuration checklist.

Comment: I have now removed civicrm, deleted all files and carried out a clean install of civiCRM.  The error still persists.  It does not appear on my local set up with the same version of drupal and civiCRM.